# Terraform tuple to map with removing empty objects?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I'm trying to create local variable for for_each loop in other resource, but can't make a local map as expected.

The following is what I tried. (Terraform 0.12)

**Expected map to loop**

```
temple_list = { "test2-role" = "test-test2-role", ... }
```

**main.tf**

```
locals {
  tmpl_list = flatten([ 
    for role in keys(var.roles) : {
      for tmpl_vars in values(var.roles[role].tmpl_vars) : 
        role => "test-${role}" if tmpl_vars == "SECRET"
    }
  ])
}

output "tmpl_list" {
  value = local.tmpl_list
}

variable "roles" {
    type = map(object({
        tmpl_vars = map(string)
        tags = map(string)
    }))
    
    default = {
        "test-role" = {
            tmpl_vars = {test = "y"}
            tags = { test = "xxx"}
        }
            "test2-role" = {
            tmpl_vars = { token = "SECRET" }
            tags = {}
        }
        "test3-role" = {
            tmpl_vars = {test = "x"}
            tags = {}
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**
comes from merge

```
    | var.roles is map of object with 3 elements

Call to function "merge" failed: arguments must be maps or objects, got
"tuple".
```

***Without merge***

```
locals {
  tmpl_list = flatten([ 
    for role in keys(var.roles) : {
      for tmpl_vars in values(var.roles[role].tmpl_vars) : 
        role => "test-${role}" if tmpl_vars == "SECRET"
    }
  ])
}

output "tmpl_list" {
  value = local.tmpl_list
}

variable "roles" {
    type = map(object({
        tmpl_vars = map(string)
        tags = map(string)
    }))
    
    default = {
        "test-role" = {
            tmpl_vars = {test = "y"}
            tags = { test = "xxx"}
        }
            "test2-role" = {
            tmpl_vars = { token = "SECRET" }
            tags = {}
        }
        "test3-role" = {
            tmpl_vars = {test = "x"}
            tags = {}
        }
    }
}
```

**Result of no merge**

```
tmpl_list = [
  {},
  {
    "test2-role" = "test-test2-role"
  },
  {},
]
```

I tried other functions like tomap(), but it seems not working for me.
(Also I'm not sure why empty ones are created.)

How can I convert this tuple to a map without empty ones?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it in two steps:

1. Convert it to the filtered list of objects:

```
locals {  
  result = flatten([
    for role, role_value in var.roles: [
      for tmpl_vars in role_value.tmpl_vars: {
        key = role
        value = "test-${role}"
      } if tmpl_vars == "SECRET"
    ]
  ])
}
```

`local.result` would have following value:

```
[
  {
    "key" = "test2-role"
    "value" = "test-test2-role"
  },
]
```

2. Then it's easy to convert it into the map with `for`:

```
my_map = { for item in local.result: item.key => item.value }
```

which gives:

```
{
  "test2-role" = "test-test2-role"
}
```